# Inner joining to a select statement where the inner select statement's where clause references the outer select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

This is a slimmed down query of my greater problem, but the gist is that I'm trying to inner join to a select where the select is limited by the outer select.  Is that possible?   I'm getting an error about multipart identifier S.Item and S.SerialNum on the inner select.

The gist is this, we have to group by the item/serial, and the query is big enough, we don't want to go back and group everything in the entire query for this minor join.

```
SELECT S.Item, S.SerialNum, S.ReceiveDate
    FROM SALES S
    INNER JOIN (SELECT W.Item, W.SerialNum, MIN(W.SalesDate)
                    FROM WARRANTY W
                    WHERE W.Item        = S.Item    AND
                          W.SerialNum   = S.SerialNum
                    GROUP BY Item, SerialNum, SalesDate) WW
        ON S.Item = WW.Item AND WW.SerialNum
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.. but from the looks of that query, remove your inner `WHERE W.Item...` clause and include that in the `ON` statement. Inner joins automatically do what it appears your `WHERE` clause is trying to do..

Comment: You outer query does not reference any variables in the inner query.  So, it is just acting as a filter.  Did you intend to include minSalesDate in the outer query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did intend to include that, whoops.  Hand typed the query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you have your `JOIN` reference in the wrong place.

```
SELECT S.Item, S.SerialNum, S.ReceiveDate
FROM SALES S
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT W.Item, W.SerialNum, MIN(W.SalesDate) MinSalesDate
    FROM WARRANTY W
    GROUP BY Item, SerialNum
) WW
        ON S.Item = WW.Item 
       AND S.SerialNum = WW.SerialNum
```

Edit, based on your comment about filtering, you can place a `WHERE` clause on your inner `SELECT`:

```
SELECT S.Item, S.SerialNum, S.ReceiveDate, WW.MinSalesDate
FROM SALES S
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT W.Item, W.SerialNum, MIN(W.SalesDate) MinSalesDate
    FROM WARRANTY W
    WHERE yourFilter here
    GROUP BY Item, SerialNum
) WW
        ON S.Item = WW.Item 
       AND S.SerialNum = WW.SerialNum
```

Comment: Also `SalesDate` shouldn't be in the `GROUP BY` and `MIN(W.SalesDate)` needs an alias.

Comment: So I can't put a `where` clause in the inner `select` statement?  The purpose being, some of the results have an "Expired" status, so I added `MIN(EXPIRED)` and did a `group by` on it, then joined `ON EXPIRED = 0`.  I'm wondering if there are more complicated ones where I won't be able to do that though.

Comment: @AlexK yes, you can place a `WHERE` clause on the inner `select`. But you cannot reference an outer table in an inner select. All references take place in the `ON` statement

Comment: @AlexK Did you try this ? `SELECT S.Item, S.SerialNum, S.ReceiveDate
FROM SALES S
Where Exists
(
 SELECT W.Item, W.SerialNum, MIN(W.SalesDate)
    FROM WARRANTY W
    WHERE W.Item        = S.Item    AND
          W.SerialNum   = S.SerialNum
    GROUP BY Item, SerialNum
)
     `

Comment: @bluefeet Ahh that explains it.  That was mainly where my issue was, the where clause referencing the outer variables

Comment: @SMC I will give that a try.  I think I've modified it based on bluefeet's data to where it's working now

Answer (score 2):

You can try a common_table_expression instead of a JOIN also. [Check the WITH clause here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

It could be something like this:

```
WITH Warranty_CTE (Item, SerialNum, MinSalesDate)
AS
(
 SELECT W.Item, W.SerialNum, MIN(W.SalesDate) MinSalesDate
    FROM WARRANTY W
    GROUP BY Item, SerialNum
)
SELECT S.Item, S.SerialNum, S.ReceiveDate
FROM SALES S
INNER JOIN Warranty_CTE  WC
        ON S.Item = WC.Item 
       AND S.SerialNum = WC.SerialNum
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot too.  I think I got it working from above

Comment: Jot a NOTE about the Execution Plan of this solution: 
This solution's plan should be the same as bluefeet's solution. (So in the background it is the same process from the optimizer) But I think this statement is more readable.

Comment: I like the more readable solution for sure.  Is this any slower though?

Comment: No, as I mentioned it is the same execution plan behind. (I mean the same like Bluefeet's solution) So the performance is the same.